# Free screenshot tools

Tags: windows, software-rec, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot utilities for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows)

I'm looking for a **free** tool to help with logging bugs.  This usually consists of:

1. Taking a screenshot of the bug
2. Pasting it into mspaint/gimp/etc
3. Selecting only the relevant parts of the image (esp. with multi monitors)
4. Saving it with a format like png to keep it small

Anything good out there?

Thanks.

Comment: Who will do the logging? Screengrab (https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/1146/) for FireFox is pretty nice and simple to use. It allows you to copy a selection of the window.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice for firefox, but I'm looking for a more universal tool.

Comment: How about explaining the -1 here?  I don't get it.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate but the other question's page is now "page not found" (smh). Here's the last copy of the questions (and its answers) I could find: https://web.archive.org/web/20121102050437/https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScreenHunter...clean and beautiful to use.

http://www.wisdom-soft.com/products/screenhunter_free.htm

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out.

Comment: Looks like this will do what I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's one built it into Windows 7 itself called Snipping Tool. Click START and type *Snip* and it ought to show up in your list of programs.

Features include Free form capture / rectangular capture / windows capture or full screen capture.

After capture, you can use rudimentary marking tools like a highlighter / pen / eraser etc.

You can save the resulting clip as PNG / GIF / JPG / HTML (MHT) and also email the resulting clip from within the applet.

An extended list of freeware screen capture tools is [available here](http://www.snapfiles.com/freeware/gmm/fwscreen.html).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by a "screenshot of the bug"? Do you mean a screenshot of the unhandled exception dialog box? What do you mean by "logging bugs"? Do you mean saving information about an unhandled exception to a location on disk, or committing said information to a SQL Server database, or sending said information to a remote location via email or some other protocol?

If the answer to these questions is yes, I don't see what value the image is adding that you can't already get from the exception. You can handle and log this information using an unhandled exception handler.

Setting up the handler:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

A handler:

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(
    object sender,
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e
) {
    var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    // log the exception  
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point.

Comment: Hey Jason, next time try and read my question before you answer it with your own questions.  If you have questions put them in comments in my question.  You'd think someone with as much rep as you have would have figured that out already.

Comment: @subt13: I gave what I believe is a valuable answer despite your unclear question. I can refine it further with additional guidance from you.

Comment: Funny how you're the only person who thinks my question is unclear.  I'd say majority wins here.  I'm thankful you tried to answer my question, but I didn't find it valuable, and I'm free to say what I want.

Comment: @subt13: I never said you aren't free to say what you want. I like the defensive tact you seem to have taken to this whole thing. Next, I'm not sure how you drew the conclusion that I'm the only person who finds your question unclear. Lastly, for what it's worth, the majority gets things wrong a lot.

Comment: @Jason - Talk about being unclear.  You're the one who got defensive by blurting out such a negative first comment.  When someone accuses me of "missing the point" when it's my question, then I have every right to respond in a cogent manner.  If you don't like it, then go away.  Oh, and by the way, stackoverflow is about as democratic as you can get, so when you say: "the majority gets things wrong a lot" you're being a hypocrite.

Comment: @subt13: You misused "cogent" and "hypocrite," seem to have a bad understanding of democracy, are quick to respond defensively, even when it's being pointed out to you that you are responding so, and even come across as a little aggressive. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like I made my point.  I don't need luck.  Have fun flaming on some other person's perfectly good and clear question.

Comment: @subt13: It's glaringly obvious that you have a lot of maturing to do.

Comment: At least I can admit it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ducklink Screen Capture](http://www.ducklink.com/)

I found it while searching for a screen capture tool that auto-scrolls to get the full length of a web page.

It has three other modes (rectangle/polygon region, window, fullscreen) and you can do all your steps 1-4 directly from Ducklink. Additionally, you can add annotations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something specifically for capturing information for bug reports, consider using [BugShooter](http://www.bugshooting.com/). It has extra features for testers, like the ability to automatically post a screenshot into a bug tracker like JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Gadwin PrintScreen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) for almost 2 years now
nice features:
- saves the file in what format and where you want it
- it works in the background, you just press the PrintScreen button and it creates the file in your folder, then you can postprocess it how you like it